# How to write test for VSCode extenstion

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, vscode-extensions

I would like to create a test to verify the operation of yoyo.transferUpperCase.
I am wondering if I have to create a mock to reproduce getText in the test.
However, I do not know how to create a mock and how to execute the command I created in the test file.
I don't know what code to write. Does anyone know what to do?

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";

function isAlphabet(str: string): boolean {
  return /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(str);
}

function replaceSelection(editor: vscode.TextEditor, newText: string) {
  const selection = editor.selection;
  editor.edit((editBuilder) => {
    editBuilder.replace(selection, newText);
  });
}

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
    "yoyo.transferUpperCase",
    () => {
      const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
      if (!editor) {
        vscode.window.showErrorMessage("No active editor");
        return;
      }

      const selection = editor.selection;
      const getText = editor.document.getText(selection);
      const upperText = isAlphabet(getText) ? getText.toUpperCase() : getText;

      replaceSelection(editor, upperText);
    },
  );

  context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

export function deactivate() {}
```

I thought about writing a test like this, but it did not work.

```
const assert = require("assert");
const vscode = require("vscode");
const extension = require("../src/extension");

suite('Extension Test Suite', () => {
  vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Start all tests.');

  test('success transfer upper case', () => {
    const editor = {
      selection: new vscode.Selection(0, 0, 0, 6),
      document: {
        getText: (selection: vscode.Selection) => 'abcDEF',
      },
    } as vscode.TextEditor;

    extension.activate({
      subscriptions: [],
    } as vscode.ExtensionContext);

    vscode.commands.executeCommand('yoyo.transferUpperCase');

    assert.strictEqual(editor.document.getText(), 'ABCDEF');
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you want a unit test or [integration test](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/testing-extension)?